# Groovy: json get value of id based on child value

Tags: json, grails

I have a json as below:

```
[
   {
      "id":6619137,
      "oid":"6fykq37gm60x",
      "key":{
         "key":"6619137"
      },
      "name":"Prod",
      "planKey":{
         "key":"PDP"
      },
      "environments":[
         {
            "id":6225923,
            "key":{
               "key":"6619137-6225923"
            },
            "name":"Production",
            "deploymentProjectId":6619137,
         }
      ],
   },
   {
      "id":6619138,
      "oid":"6fykq37gm60y",
      "key":{
         "key":"6619138"
      },
      "name":"QA",
      "planKey":{
         "key":"QDP"
      },
      "environments":[
         {
            "id":6225924,
            "key":{
               "key":"6619138-6225924"
            },
            "name":"QA",
            "deploymentProjectId":6619138,
         }
      ],
   },
]
```

I can use the below code to extract the value of id and environments.id based on the name value. projectID will give 6619137 and environmentID will give 6225923

```
def e = json.planKey.find{it.name=='Prod'}
def projectID = e.id
def environmentID = e.environments[0].id
```

However, when I try to extract the value of id and environments.id based on the plankey.key value (e.g. PDP or QDP), using the same format above returns me an error of `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'id' on null object at Script60.run(Script60.groovy:52)`

```
def e = json.planKey.find{it.planKey=='{key=PDP}'}
def projectID = e.id
def environmentID = e.environments[0].id
```

Is there a way I can get the projectID with the plankey key value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of your JSON object as a key/value map with multiple levels.  There is no such item as

```
json.find{it.planKey=='{key=PDP}'}
```

However, you can find with values at any level, like this:

```
def e = json.find{it.planKey.key == "PDP"}
```

If you have a structure where planKey may  not exist, or it doesn't always have `key`, that's a bit different, but from your question it sounds like that's not the case here.

EDIT: correcting syntax based on comment below.

Comment: I see, thanks for the suggestion. Managed to find it with
`def e = json.find{it.planKey.key == "PDP"}`